# Ajax: Upload the image to choose among many others

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am going to go crazy if I don't find a solution to this. I drag and drop many pictures to a drag area and then **I want to choose anyone of them as to upload it** on the server. However, with the following code I always upload the last one...

**HTML code:**

```
<form id="upload" action="upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <div id="dragarea"></div>
      <input type="file" id="fileselect"  name="fileselect[]" multiple="multiple"/>
</form>
```

**JS code** which is executed upon a click event on the image file I have dropped inside the dragarea:

```
var fd = new FormData($('#upload')[0]);
  $.ajax({
        method:"POST",
        url:"upload.php",
        dataType:"json",
        data:fd, 
        contentType: false,      
        cache: false,             
        processData:false,  
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
        } 
   })
```

and my upload.php

```
if (!empty($_FILES)) 
  {   
      $sourcePath = $_FILES['fileselect']['tmp_name']; 
      echo json_encode($sourcePath);  
      $targetPath = $_FILES['fileselect']['name'];           
      move_uploaded_file($sourcePath,$targetPath) ;
  }
```

***What changes do I have to do as to send the clicking image for uploading and then get it on the server?***

Thank you very much

Comment: Have you just copied and pasted random bits of unrelated code? How or why could any of this do anything you want? Please make a bit more of an effort. Or if you don't know what you are doing, please hire someone to do the work for you.